# How to unhide a div given that a jsp el is not null?

Tags: css, jsp, bootstrap-4, el

I wanted to know whats the proper way of hiding a div unless some conditions are met. I am trying to add a div that contains a login error and would only appear once there is an error.

```
<div id= "error" class="alert alert-danger" hidden="hidden" role="alert">
    ${loginError} 
</div>
```

I tried adding a script but it did not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(null != request.getAttribute("loginError")){
        document.getElementById("error").hidden = "";

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to realize, **where** and **when** which code is executed - JSP on the server, when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. **before** the response is sent to the browser), and Javascript in the browser, **after** the browser receives the **already generated** response. Thus, there is no `request` variable in JS, so

```
if(null != request.getAttribute("loginError")){
```

makes no sense. I would suggest the following:

```
<div id= "error" class="alert alert-danger" ${ empty loginError ? '' : 'hidden'} role="alert">
```

(The `hidden` attribute does not need to have a value, if it is present, the element will be hidden - no matter what its value is.)

Answer (score 0):

You need change your value hidden to false. Empty string add atribute hidden to element anyway. So to change state of hiddenness of html element you should use boolean values. 
`document.getElementById("error").hidden = false;`